# Trouble solving generated output

Tags: java, arrays, return, output, equation-solving

I'm fairly new to java and am having trouble preparing for an exam. This sample question asks to show work to give the exact output generated by this code:

```
public class Lab7Experiment extends JApplet
{
    int x=3, y=-3, z=5;
    int someValues [] = {2, -6, 4, -4, 6, -2};

    public void init()
    {
        char y = 'y';
        z=10;
        System.out.println("Print 1 x,y,z, = "+x+" "+y+" "+z);
        y= sub1(x,y,z);
        System.out.println("Print 2 x,y,z, = "+x+" "+y+" "+z);
        x= sub2(x, someValues);
        System.out.println("Print 3 x,y,z, = "+x+" "+y+" "+z);
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            System.out.println("Print "+(i+4)+" "+someValues[i*2]+" "+someValues[i*2+1]);
    }
    public char sub1(int a, char b, int c)
    {
        if (a>=c)
            return b;
        else
        {
            c=15;
            z=25;
            return 'z';
        }
    }
    public int sub2(int x, int [] anArray)
    {
        int y=0;
        for(int i=anArray.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            if (anArray[i] > x)
            {
                anArray[i]=x;
                y++;
            }

        }
        x=100;
        return y;
    }

}
```

I'm having trouble understanding how the someValues array and anArray are used when generating this output. I've run it in Eclipse so I'm able to check my answers, but I'm not sure why the generated output results are what they are. Can someone explain this to me? Would appreciate it so much. Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What values do you see when you run the code, and which values did you expect to see instead?

Comment: @markspace Yes! When I run it, I see:   

    Print 1 x,y,z, = 3 y 10
    Print 2 x,y,z, = 3 z 25
    Print 3 x,y,z, = 2 z 25
    Print 4 2 -6
    Print 5 3 -4
    Print 6 3 -2.

Since there isn’t a “Print 4, 5, etc” written in the System.out.println(); , where do these come from? And for Print 2 and 3, why is ‘z’ now in the place of ‘y’? I’m not even sure where to start when solving this(we must solve it by hand).

Answer (score 0):

It is a long answer(s) and not an issue to solve...

BTW:

1. Print 1 x,y,z, = 3 y 10

because class variable `x` = 3: `int x=3`
then local variable char y = 'y' is used and `z` changed to 10 `z=10;`

2. Print 2 x,y,z, = 3 z 25
   because class variable `x` still untouched. in `sub1`: 3 is not >= 10 (passed `z`), so `else` branch:

   ```
       `c=15;` does not change passed `x` Java is `pass-by-value`
       `z=25;` changes class variable `z` to 25
       return 'z';
   ```

   then local variable y now is 'z'
3. after sub2 you have:

   `class variable x = 2`
    `class variable y =-3`
    `class variable z = 25`
    `local variable y = 'y'`
   UPDATED:     `class variable someValues [] = {2, -6, 3, -4, 3, -2};`

then follow last loop to get Print 4,5 and 6 from `someValues` as:

```
`Print 4 2 -6`
`Print 5 3 -4`
`Print 6 3 -2`
```

good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm starting to get it. One thing I don't understand, though... for Print 5, how is the second value 3? Since someValues[2] would pull a value of 4?

Comment: Sorry - my bad - wrong copy paste. Look now at updated `someValues`. Actually sub2 replaces all values greater than x with x (3) and returns how many were replaced which is 2 and then x becomes that.